# Array of pointers whose elements point to another array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

What I need very precisely is an array `A[10]` and each of its element pointing to the respective element of array `B[10]` whose each element store its index.

Hence, `A[1]` points to `B[1]` and `B[1]` has value of 1.
So, when I call *`A[1]` or `*B[1]`, I get 1.

I know it can be super easy if the array `B[10]` is not an array of pointers but of integers but I need this for another purpose.

This is what I did but segmentation fault was offered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *A[10];
    int *B[10];
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        A[i] = B[i];
        *B[i] = i;
        printf("\n%d %d",*A[i],*B[i]);
    }
}
```

By the way, I am not very proficient in pointers.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @mr.loop your code works fine. Provide complete code that can be compiled.

Comment: `x = *y[1];` is undefined behavior. You are de-referencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky My bad that I messed up the question. Edited finally to make it precise and reproducible.

Comment: @Lundin Edited to reflect the original question.

Comment: None of your pointers in both arrays are initialized, they point nowhere. Therefore dereferencing them is undefined behaviour, a seg fault in your case.

Comment: according to your description `B` should be an array of int , not an array of pointer

Comment: "A[10] and each of its element pointing to the respective element of array B[10]". Then they cannot possibly have the same type.

Comment: For `B[n]` to have a value, it cannot be a pointer. Simple as that. You cannot "store values in pointers". You can have a sign saying "house" pointing at your house. But you can't store things inside the sign just because it says "house". It doesn't become a house just because it points at one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commented code :

```
int main() {
    int *A[10];   // an array of 10 pointers, each of them pointing nowhere
    int *B[10];   // an array of 10 pointers, each of them pointing nowhere

    // now each array a and b contain 10 uninitialized pointers,
    // they contain ideterminate values and they point nowhere
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        A[i] = B[i];     // copy an uninitialized pointer
                         // this usually works but it's pointless

        *B[i] = i;       // you assign i to the int pointed by *B[i]
                         // but as *B[i] points nowhere you end up with a segfault

        printf("\n%d %d",*A[i],*B[i]);  // you never get here because the previous
                                        // line terminates the program with a segfault,
                                        // but you'd get a segfault here too for 
                                        // the same reason
    }
}
```

Your program is basically equivalent to this:

```
int main() {
    int *a;     // a is not initialized, it points nowhere
    *a = 1;     // probably you'll get a segfault here
}
```

Accessing the thing pointed by a pointer is called *dereferencing the pointer*. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer  results in *undefined behaviour* (google that term), most likely you'll get a seg fault.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int* A[10];
  int B[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    A[i] = &B[i];
    B[i] = i;
    printf("%d %d\n", *A[i], B[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But is there a way to do this using pointer array rather than int array. Its because some of the elements of B have to store index and other point somewhere.

Comment: @mr.loop a way to do what? This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should tell us what you are _actually_ trying to do by asking an other question. The problem with your code is that the pointers in the second array point nowhere.